# Delay of 500ms for every command send to the serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port, delay

I have a Graphical User Interface which I use to control my hardware via RS232 commands. I have 40 commands and each command has a button assigned on the GUI , after a click the command is send to the Hardware.

The hardware is slow and sometimes freezes as the commands from the GUI are send at a faster rate.I therefore want to add a delay from the software side before they are send serially to the port.

I dont need a buffer to store the commands , they can just be deleted if the user tries to send any commands in the delay period.
How can this be achieved in Csharp without letting the GUI Freeze. 
So basically what I need is a communication handler to control the commands send on serial port

Comment: have you tried using `Task.Delay()`?

Comment: No I haven't I will try

Comment: `SerialPort` and underlying `Stream` are not thread safe. Are you sure that the device freezes because commands are sent too fast and not because multiple writers interfere with each other?

Answer (score 0):

You can hold your program by calling `Task.Delay(int ms)`. This command creates a task 
that completes after specified ms.